# Post increment query in C

Tags: c

I am a web developer and a programmer in varied of languages and that is what confuses me as when I return back to older languages. Someone could please answer this as this is not being answered by me and the quiz is basically taking my answer wrong.

```
    int m, n;
    m=6;
    n=m++;
    printf("%d %d", m,n);

    -----------
    Options
    a: 6 6
    b: 6 7  ---> the answer i think is right
    c: 7 6  ---> the right answer by quiz server
    d: 7 7
```

Please help me by explaining the answer, just because I think the answer was reversed

Comment: Make that `printf("%d %d", n,m);` and schwuppdiwupp `b` is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit of a trick question.

```
m=6;  //simple enough, m now equals 6
n=m++;  //post increment operator returns old value so n becomes 6.
```

But m remember is incremented to 7.

so now, m = 7 and n=6

That is exactly what is printed out.

Easiest way to check is to paste the code into a debugger and step through it. You can create temporary variables for finer details if required.

Answer (score 5):

The post-increment operator returns the original value *then* increments.

This means that your quiz server is correct.

```
n=m++;
```

assigns the original value of `m` to `n` then increments `m`, leaving

```
n=6, m=7
```

Comment: This answer is subtly wrong. See my comment on Paul's answer.

Answer (score 4):

The quiz server is correct:

```
m=6;     // m = 6
n=m++;   // n = m = 6; m = m + 1 = 7;
```

Note that the post-increment of `m` above occurs *after* the assignment.

Comment: Your last statement is subtly wrong. The c standard does not require the side effects of incrementing and assignment to occur in any order. A correct statement would be that the value assigned is the value before incrementing. The assignment could come after the increment if the original value was stored in a temporary.

Comment: @Eric: true, but I don't think this makes any difference as far as the programmer (particularly a noob programmer) is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not going to tell anything different but the same as all the above did, but i can provide a few more examples

```
// Example 1
m = 6 ; / very simple no explanation here

// Example 2
m++ = 6; 
/** 
    This can be rewritten as
    m = 6;
    m = m+1;

**/ 

// Example 4
n = m++; // kind of your case
/**
   This can be re qritted as
   n = m;
   m = m+1;
**/

// Example 5

n++ = m++ + 1; // little complex

/**
   This can be rewritten as
   n = m+1;
   n++;
   m++;
**/
```

simple theory

pre-increment works before assignment and post-increment after assignment not necessarily true though because there are cases where extensive use of these operator yields results that are unpredictable.